# Get Unicode of a character in Groovy

Tags: groovy, utf-16, utf

Is there any way in Groovy so that I can get Unicode equivalent of any character? e.g.

Suppose a method getUnicode(char c). A call getUnicode('÷') should return \u00f7.

Comment: Characters *are* Unicode in Groovy (well, technically they are UTF-16 code units, which *usually, but not always* are equivalent to Unicode codepoints). What you're looking for is the Unicode escape syntax of Java (which always references UTF-16 code units i.e. `char` values itself, fittingly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm gonna hit you with this:

```
println( "\\u${'÷'.getBytes("UTF-16")[2..3].collect { String.format('%02x',it) }.join('')}" )

println("\\u${'÷'.getBytes("UTF-16BE").collect { String.format('%02x',it) }.join('')}")
```

The trick is to get the UTF-16 version of the bytes otherwise it won't work as you expect.  However, `getBytes` returns **4** bytes instead of 2 because it includes the UTF BOM on the front of it.  So splicing out indexes 2 to 3 will isolate just the characters you need.  The format for hex with `String.format`, and join 'em back to a string tack on \u characters with a Groovy GString and bam you cooking.

Comment: `UTF-16BE` should produce the same output as `UTF-16`, except it will not produce the BOM, making your splicing call unnecessary.